# Qt QProcess not deprecated function not working

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use QProcess to launch another program.

Originally I used:

```cpp
    QString _commandLine;
    BuildCommandLine(_commandLine, fileUrl);

    QProcess::startDetached(_commandLine);
```

This works, launching the program, but the function is deprecated, so I want to use the proper function:

```cpp
    QStringList _arguments = {
        // List of arguments
    };

    QProcess* _process = new QProcess();
    _process->setProgram(GetProgramUrl());
    _process->setArguments(_arguments);
    _process->setStandardOutputFile("log.txt");

    _process->startDetached();

    QString program = _process->program();
    QStringList argList = _process->arguments();
```

But this doesn't launch the program.

Some notes:

- The argument list is valid, if I join the list in a single string along with the program url, it works as command line and the program launches using the deprecated function.
- I also connected the "started" signal of the process to a message to see if the process correctly starts and the signal triggers.

Any ideas?

Comment: *"But this doesn't work."*, a friendly hint: never write this in a programming question. It doesn't mean anything. You asking the question already pretty much implies, it doesn't work. Instead, _tell what the program does, and what you want it to do,_ and how these are different (if it's not clear).

Answer (score 2):

```
_process->startDetached();
_process->waitForFinished();
```

These two are mutually exclusive. You can't wait on detached process, because it is no longer a child process. Choose one or the other.

---

> The rest of the signals don't trigger.

This is expected for a detached process.

Comment: I mixed the two versions of the code I was testing. I already edited it, thank you.

Comment: @Tharrik Check the edit.

Comment: Yes, I checked it and the `start()` function triggers the rest of the signals, while `startDetached()` only triggers the started signal. Nonetheless, this doesn't solve my problem. Thanks for the help, anyway. :)

Comment: @Tharrik Why do you want to detach the process? Maybe you could detach it when your program exits, if it  _really_ needs to remain rumning.

Comment: The original program manages files to be opened by the detached program. It could be a child process but it's not important for the issue. Detached or not, the program is not launching.

Comment: @Tharrik So just don't detach it, if it works then?